# Are Spark DataFrames ever implicitly cached?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have recently understood that Spark DAGs get executed lazily, and intermediate results are never cached unless you explicitly call `DF.cache()`.

Now I've ran an experiment that should give me different random numbers every time, based on that fact:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

df = spark.range(0, 3)
df = df.select("id", rand().alias('rand'))

df.show()
```

Executing these lines multiple times gives me different random numbers each time, as expected. But if the computed values (`rand()` in this case) are never stored, then calling just `df.show()` repeatedly should give me new random numbers every time, because the 'rand' column is not cached, right?

```
df.show()
```

This command called a second time gives me the same random numbers as before though. So the values are stored somewhere now, which I thought does not happen.

Where is my thinking wrong? And could you give me a minimal example of non-caching that results in new random numbers every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random seed parameter of `rand()` is set when `rand().alias('rand')` is called inside the `select` method and does not change afterwards. Therefore, calling `show` multiple times does always use the same random seed and hence the result is the same.

You can see it more clearly when you return the result of `rand().alias('rand')` by itself, which also shows the random seed parameter:

```
>>> rand().alias('rand')
Column<b'rand(166937772096155366) AS `rand`'>
```

When providing the seed directly, it will show up accordingly:

```
>>> rand(seed=22).alias('rand') 
Column<b'rand(22) AS `rand`'>
```

The random seed is set when calling `rand()` and is stored as a column expression within the `select` method. Therefore the result is the same. You will get different results when reevaluating `rand()` everytime like `df.select("id", rand().alias('rand')).show()`.

Comment: Thanks! So my assumption was right, but the experiment design was wrong :)
The random numbers get recomputed every time, but with the same initial seed.